# Averaging Every Other Cell in a Row

Tags: excel

In Excel, I am trying to average every other cell in a row (i.e., from L3 to AVG3). In other words, I want to average the values in L3, N3, P3, R3,...AVG3. However, I'd also like blank values to be excluded from the average calculation.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, shown both row and column...

[image]

You can use averageifs() and deal with blanks or errors as you need, left as an exercise for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in a single formula if you want to:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN(L3:AVG3))*(L3:AVG3<>""),L3:AVG3))
```

or if you have Excel 365:

```
=AVERAGE(FILTER(L3:AVG3,ISEVEN(COLUMN(L3:AVG3))))
```